# Assigning values and passing struct as parameter

Tags: c, struct, parameters

- To asign a *char value* into the struct 'field', I *have to* use *strcpy* ?

I tried this:

```
struct student{

   char name[50];
   int  age;
};  


int main(){

struct student std;

std.name = "john";  //Doesnt work
strcpy(std.name, "john");  //It DOES work
std.age = 20;

return 0;}
```

Why when comes to *char* I can not simply use the ' = ' to assign a value ?

- How may I pass a struct initialized in *main(){}* as a parameter to a function and change it's values inside the function without the need of a return. 
  Do I just use the '*'  like:

  ```
     void MyFunction(struct student *std){            
     std->Name = "John";
     std->Age = 20; 
     }

     int main(){
     struct student me;    
     Myfunction(me);
     }
  ```

Is that the correct way to do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter which way you pass the struct (by value or by pointer), you cannot directly assign a string literal to a char array. You can only use strcpy or strncpy or something else that copies the characters one by one.

But there is a workaround, you can directly assign struct to another one. C compiler will perform a bitwise copy of the struct.

```
struct student s1;
strcpy(s1.name, "john");
s1.age = 10;
struct student s2;
s2 = s1; // now s2 is exactly same as s1.
```

Attach an example of use pointer to pass struct:

```
void handle_student(struct student *p) { ... }
int main() {
  struct student s1;
  handle_student(&s1);
}
```

Comment: better to use `strncpy(s1.name, "john", sizeof s1.name);` so buffer size is warranted not to overflow.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an additional information

While declaring the structure variable, it can be initialized as below.

```
int main(){
    struct student s1 = {"John", 21};
     //or
   struct student s = {.name= "John" };

}
```

Comment: You cannot use that in older ansi-c compilers for automatic variables like the ones you have used in your example.  Even, the .name notation is only allowed in newer ansi-c compilers.